# Confusion about Nelson's proof of Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Nelson's proof of Liouville's theorem (in the case $n=2$) is as follows:

> Consider a bounded harmonic function on Euclidean space. Since
>   it is harmonic, its value at any point is its average over any sphere,
>   and hence over any ball, with the point as center. Given two points,
>   choose two balls with the given points as centers and of equal radius.
>   If the radius is large enough, the two balls will coincide except for an
>   arbitrarily small proportion of their volume. Since the function is
>   bounded, the averages of it over the two balls are arbitrarily close,
>   and so the function assumes the same value at any two points. Thus
>   a bounded harmonic function on Euclidean space is a constant.

I tried to formalize it.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic bounded function. If $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ we have that
\begin{align*}
        |f(z)-f(w)| &= \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\left|\int_{D(z,r)}f(x+iy)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y - \int_{D(w,r)}f(x+iy)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\right|\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\left|\int_{A}f(x+iy)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y - \int_{B}f(x+iy)\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\right| \\
        &\leq \frac{2}{\pi r^2}(\sup |f|)\int_A 1\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y \\
        &= \frac{2}{\pi r^2}(\sup |f|) \left(2r^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{2r}\right)-\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{4r^2-d^2}, \right)
    \end{align*}

where $d=|z-w|$. Observe what are $A$ and $B$ in the following drawing:
[image]
I would expect that the right hand side tends to $0$ when $r\to\infty$. However, that is not the case. How should I formalize Nelson's proof?

Comment: I get that $|A| = \mathcal O(r)$.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you computed $\int_A 1\,dx\,dy$, because I agree with amsmath that the answer looks suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation of the area of $A$ doesn't look correct.

It would be easier to bound the integral as follows: the width of $A$ is never more than $d$, and its $y$-coordinates are bounded between $-r$ and $r$.  Thus $\int_A 1\,dx\,dy \le \int_{-r}^r d\,dy = 2rd$.

Comment: I don't agree with this argumentation. Think of two parallel lines between the lines $y=-r$ and $y=r$ with "x-distance" $d$ whose slope is very small. Making the slope smaller and smaller, the area between the lines tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @amsmath: No, it doesn't!  The area of such a parallelogram is exactly $2rd$ regardless of the slope.

Comment: Nate, you are right, of course.

Comment: I upvoted for your answer because I think it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's calculate the volume $|A|$ of $A$. WLOG I let $z=0$ and $w=d > 0$. Then
$$
\frac{|A|}2 = \int_{d/2}^{r+d}\sqrt{r^2-(x-d)^2}\,dx - \int_{d/2}^{r}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx = \int_{-d/2}^{d/2}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx.
$$
Substituting $x = r\sin t$ gives
$$
\frac{|A|}2 = r^2\int_{-\arcsin(d/2r)}^{\arcsin(d/2r)}\cos^2t\,dt = \frac{r^2}2\left[\cos t\sin t + t\right]_{-\arcsin(d/2r)}^{\arcsin(d/2r)}.
$$
As $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$,
$$
\frac{|A|}2 = r^2\left(\frac{d}{2r}\sqrt{1-\frac{d^2}{4r^2}}+\arcsin\frac{d}{2r}\right)\,\le\,r^2\left(\frac d{2r} + \arcsin\frac d{2r}\right).
$$
Now, for small positive $x$ we have $\arcsin x\le 2x$, hence $|A|\le 3dr$ for large $r$.